# How to set up CIAbot for github repository

Tags: git, github, irc, bots

As in the title, I want to know how to set up the CIAbot for a github repository.

Answer (score 13):

From this [post](http://www.bitcoin.org/smf/index.php?topic=2629.0) (found through a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=CIAbot%20github)).

```
On your GitHub account
 - Click Admin on the GitHub project page.
 - Click Service Hooks.
 - Click CIA in the list
 - Check [X] Active

Now go to http://cia.vc and create an account.
 - Create a new repository and enter the info
 - Fill the website URL with https://github.com/your_login/your_repo.git
 - Click Bots, Add bot and choose an IRC channel
```

*Note:* If more than 5 commits are pushed simultaneously, only the last message will be announced (see [support message](http://support.github.com/discussions/post-receive-issues/2-github-irc-bot-getting-kicked-for-flooding)).

*Note 2:* This [project](https://github.com/tekkub/tekMapEnhancer/tree/) from [@tekkub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243559) is hosted on github and monitored with [CIA](http://cia.vc/stats/project/tekMapEnhancer)

Comment: I got the bot running, but for some reason it doesn't see any commits. Is the URL format the same for repositories owned by organization?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa the url format of a repository owned by a organization would be [https://github.com/organization_name/repo_name.git](https://github.com/organization_name/repo_name.git)

Comment: Ok. Got it (you can directly paste the HTTPS URL from github project page box). However, CIA doesn't see changes in my project for some reason, still trying to figure out why. The bot itself works and joined the channel.

Answer (score 0):

[CIA bot for gavin's bitcoin branch on github](http://www.bitcoin.org/smf/index.php?action=printpage;topic=2629.0)

Comment: @Azzurio: You answer two days later than me, provide the same link than I previously did and you get the bounty... Congrats!

Comment: @nulltoken: thank you, but i think if you got the answer from external reference, you should mention this reference or article; to keep author rights!

Comment: @Azzurio: You're welcome! The first line of my answer is "From this post (found through a Google search)." with two links (first one to the post, second one to the result of the google search) ;-)